# October CMS javascript event on backend repeater fields

Tags: jquery, octobercms

Using October CMS for a project, I try to add a javascript event on backend repeater fields. But it seems dynamically added input field by repeater doesn't see by the javascript while it works with others input field of the same form

my script below:

```
<script>
  $('input').on('keypress', function(e){
      // only numbers
      if ( charCode < 48 || charCode > 57 ) {
          return false;
      }
      return true;
  });
</script>
```

have you some idea to make it works ?

thanks in advance & regards,
Patrick

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You stated:-
*it seems dynamically added input field by repeater doesn't see by the javascript while it works with others input field of the same form*

It is a correct behavior because event binding has been done when page was loaded and you have created new elements afterwards, so event doesn't bound on those elements.

You have to use the technique which is called event delegation. Like:

```
  $(document).on('keypress', 'input', function(e){
      // the code 
  });
```

Here in this code you can change `$(document)` to a closest static parent like any `div, form etc.`.

```
$('form').on('keypress', 'input', function(){
   // code here
});
```

---

So, the syntax is:

```
$(staticParent).on(event, selector, callback);
```

Where ***staticParent*** is the element which is the parent element when page was loaded. It should not be a dynamically created parent.

Comment: awesome :-) thank you very much Jai, you make me day :-D

Answer (score 0):

October fires an event "render" on the page after new elements are added by $.request or other methods.

So, you would prefably listen to:

```
$(window).on('render', function() {
    $('input').on('keypress', function(e){
    }
});
```

Only problem is, things will get "double" keypresses.

For that, october recommends using the foundation framework pattern. That way event listeners will only be bound once and not double if an element already exists on page.

https://octobercms.com/docs/ui/foundation

```js
+function ($) { "use strict";
    var Base = $.oc.foundation.base,
        BaseProto = Base.prototype

    var SomeDisposableControl = function (element, options) {
        this.$el = $(element)
        this.options = options || {}

        $.oc.foundation.controlUtils.markDisposable(element)
        Base.call(this)
        this.init()
    }

    SomeDisposableControl.prototype = Object.create(BaseProto)
    SomeDisposableControl.prototype.constructor = SomeDisposableControl

    SomeDisposableControl.prototype.init = function() {
        this.$el.on('click', this.proxy(this.onClick))
        this.$el.one('dispose-control', this.proxy(this.dispose))
    }

    SomeDisposableControl.prototype.dispose = function() {
        this.$el.off('click', this.proxy(this.onClick))
        this.$el.off('dispose-control', this.proxy(this.dispose))
        this.$el.removeData('oc.someDisposableControl')

        this.$el = null

        // In some cases options could contain callbacks, 
        // so it's better to clean them up too.
        this.options = null

        BaseProto.dispose.call(this)
    }

    SomeDisposableControl.DEFAULTS = {
        someParam: null
    }

    // PLUGIN DEFINITION
    // ============================

    var old = $.fn.someDisposableControl

    $.fn.someDisposableControl = function (option) {
        var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1), items, result

        items = this.each(function () {
            var $this   = $(this)
            var data    = $this.data('oc.someDisposableControl')
            var options = $.extend({}, SomeDisposableControl.DEFAULTS, $this.data(), typeof option == 'object' && option)
            if (!data) $this.data('oc.someDisposableControl', (data = new SomeDisposableControl(this, options)))
            if (typeof option == 'string') result = data[option].apply(data, args)
            if (typeof result != 'undefined') return false
        })

        return result ? result : items
    }

    $.fn.someDisposableControl.Constructor = SomeDisposableControl

    $.fn.someDisposableControl.noConflict = function () {
        $.fn.someDisposableControl = old
        return this
    }

    // Add this only if required
    $(document).render(function (){
        $('[data-some-disposable-control]').someDisposableControl()
    })

}(window.jQuery);
```

I suggest reading the above link because it explains a lot of what the gotchas etc.. and why it's important to clean up.

Personally, I expanded on the october foundation to make 'cleanup' and managing variables easier.

https://github.com/tschallacka/october-foundation/blob/master/src/october-foundation-base.js

Basically what it does is ensure that functions are automatically unbound, variables cleaned up when the element is removed from dom via a jquery commands, and are automatically bound to tagged elements when the 'render' event is fired.

with my script it would become:

```
// ..... foundation code

    Application.prototype.handlers = function(type) {
        this.bind('keypress',this.$el, this.keypressHandler);
    };

    Application.prototype.init = function() {
        /**
         * example;
         */
        this.alloc('foobar',42);
        console.log(this.foobar);
    }

    Application.prototype.keypressHandler = function(e) {
        if(!e.defaultPrevented) {
            // only numbers
            if ( charCode < 48 || charCode > 57 ) {
                e.preventDefault();
                return false;
            }
            return true;
        }
    }

//  foundation code ....
```